# Feature selection where data is skewed in shape (classification model)

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I have data where few features having skewed which is right-tailed in shape. should I need to transform these data to make standard normal distribution and check the prediction or should I drop these features and try predicting the model?

what should I need to do? because we need transformation whenever we use the regression model but 
in the classification model, do we need to do the transformation?

Answer (score 0):

This transformation is designed to help your optimizer converge, and this does not depend on whether your performing classification or regression, so you might want to consider a log transformation to try to make your data normally distributed.